# Django calender object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django

this time i have the this errors, i don't know why?
I also import from calendar import HTMLCalendar, from datetime import date,from itertools import groupby

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://article/WorkoutCalendar/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    WorkoutCalendar' object has no attribute 'get'
```

this is my the urls.py:

```
url(r"^WorkoutCalendar/$", "article.views.WorkoutCalendar"),
```

and this is my the views.py:

```
class WorkoutCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

    def __init__(self, workouts):
        super(WorkoutCalendar, self).__init__()
        self.workouts = self.group_by_day(workouts)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day != 0:
            cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
            if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                cssclass += ' today'
            if day in self.workouts:
                cssclass += ' filled'
                body = ['<ul>']
                for workout in self.workouts[day]:
                    body.append('<li>')
                    body.append('<a href="%s">' % workout.get_absolute_url())
                    body.append(esc(workout.title))
                    body.append('</a></li>')
                body.append('</ul>')
                return self.day_cell(cssclass, '%d %s' % (day, ''.join(body)))
            return self.day_cell(cssclass, day)
        return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')

    def formatmonth(self, year, month):
        self.year, self.month = year, month
        return super(WorkoutCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

    def group_by_day(self, workouts):
        field = lambda workout: staff.created_at.day
        return dict(
            [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(workouts, field)]
        )

    def day_cell(self, cssclass, body):
        return '<td class="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, body)



    def calendar(request, year, month):
        my_workouts = Staff.objects.order_by('created_at').filter(created_at__year=year,   created_at__month=month)
        cal = WorkoutCalendar(my_workouts).formatmonth(year, month)
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'calendar': mark_safe(cal),})
```

Answer (score 0):

WorkoutCalendar is not a view, so you can't map it to a URL. It seems like you meant to put `article.views.calendar` there instead.

Comment: I tryed article.views.calendar, but have the this errors :Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
list indices must be integers, not unicode

Comment: Well, then you have a bug somewhere. If you asked a new question and posted the full traceback we might be able to help.